# C++11 version of Windows EventWaitHandle

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I don't know C++ at all, but for the heck of it I tossed this together because I was talking with someone about C++ and was given the impression there is absolutely nothing quite like the windows APIs `ManualReset` and `AutoReset` `EventWaitHandle`s, so I figured I'd see if I could create one.

I think this might work - it compiles and runs but I don't really know well enough how to make a thread to test it's multi-threading off hand in C++ and don't care to try figuring it out. Figure folks here can probably tell me if I got any of the threading primitives usage completely off or have some harrible race conditions or some such.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class EventWaitHandle {

public:
    EventWaitHandle(bool handleWillCloseAfterOneWait, bool openAtStart)
        : autoReset(handleWillCloseAfterOneWait), handleOpen(openAtStart)
    { }

    void set() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> handleOpenLock(handleOpenLocker);
            handleOpen = true;
        }

        handleOpenSignal.notify_one();
    }

    void reset() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> handleOpenLock(handleOpenLocker);
            handleOpen = false;
        }

        handleOpenSignal.notify_one();
    }

    bool wait(int millisecondsBeforeTimeout) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> handleOpenLock(handleOpenLocker);

            if (handleOpen) {
                handleOpen = !autoReset;
                return true;
            }

            if (millisecondsBeforeTimeout < 1) // Handle isn't open and we are waiting no time, punt..
                return false;

        }

        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        cout << "waiting.." << endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockJustForThisWaiter(handleOpenLocker);

        if(handleOpenSignal.wait_until(lockJustForThisWaiter, start + std::chrono::milliseconds(millisecondsBeforeTimeout)) == std::cv_status::timeout)
            return false;

        auto timeLeftToWaitInEventOfSpuriousness = std::chrono::milliseconds(millisecondsBeforeTimeout) - (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        int millisecondsLeftToWait = 0;
        millisecondsLeftToWait = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeLeftToWaitInEventOfSpuriousness).count();

        return wait(millisecondsLeftToWait);
    }

private:

    bool autoReset;

    std::condition_variable handleOpenSignal;
    std::atomic<bool> handleOpen;
    std::mutex handleOpenLocker;
};
```

That's what I want review of, this is just example usage concept:

```
int main(){
    EventWaitHandle waitHandle(true, true);

    bool open;

    open = waitHandle.wait(100);
    if (open)
        cout << "open" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not open" << endl;

    waitHandle.set();

    open = waitHandle.wait(100);
    if (open)
        cout << "open" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not open" << endl;

    waitHandle.reset();

    open = waitHandle.wait(100);
    if (open)
        cout << "open" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not open" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the good odds of a tail-call optimisation, your use of recursion seems unidiomatic and sets off alarm bells in my head. Though they are largely unfounded in a practical sense, I'd say that's enough of a warning to just perform loop-waiting with an actual loop, instead.

You could do with some documenting comments, as it's not clear to a non-WinAPI person what this class actually does.

Some of your code lines are too long to read comfortably.

I can't spot any actual bugs though.